# Category Archive

Tags: archive-template

What's is the best way to make an archive page have editable text, as opposed to hardcoding text into the template file?

Here is what I am trying as per suggestion below.

```
<?php
if(is_category( '1' ))
  echo category_description( ); 

?>
```

Am trying this but for some reason I can not get it to work. This is on an ARCHIVE page and Codex suggests using is category for archive pages.

Comment: As-written, your question cannot be answered. Please **edit your question** to include all your relevant code, in context: including your `register_post_type()` and `register_taxonomy()` calls.

Comment: guessing from your topic title, try to use the *Category Description*, possibly with a plugin to enable html code in the description.

Comment: What do you mean "*best way*"? How do you intend to define/maintain that editable text? Theme option? Something else?

Comment: sorry for not being clear folks. How can I add editable text to an archive page (and NOT hardcode it in.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard to choose "best way", when you give so few details describing your case.

There are two most common ways I can think of.

1. **Use category description**. You can then print it out in category/archive template using [`category_description`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description).
2. **Make custom page template** which will display posts from given category (or whatever you want). You can read more on this [here (Codex/Page Templates/A Page of Posts)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#A_Page_of_Posts)

Most of the times first solution should be sufficient. I would use second solution only when you have complex descriptions (you have to use a lot of formatting and some custom fields).

Comment: Krzysiek, i've edited the original question. Please let me know your thoughts.